# Show particular lines using only head and tail

Tags: ubuntu, tail, head

I want to show the 3th and the 7th lines in a file only using commands `head` and `tail` (I don't want to show the lines between the 3th and the 7th).

Comment: Yeah. I did it with sed but I want the same result using head and tail.

Comment: Well I can't make `head`s or `tail`s of why you want that but I believe the solution below should do what you need

Comment: It's just a question from a teacher

Comment: that makes it a school assignment ... please include your attempts ... also include an explanation of how your attempts failed

Comment: I did it on two commands (like in the answer below) but I want it in one command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the MULTIOS facility in the `zsh` shell:

```
$ head -n 7 file | tail -n 5 > >( head -n 1 ) > >( tail -n 1 )
line 3
line 7
```

That is, extract lines 3 through to 7 with `head -n 7 file | tail -n 5` and then get the first and last line of that.

In `bash`, this would be equivalent of

```
$ head -n 7 file | tail -n 5 | tee >( head -n 1 ) | tail -n 1 
line 3
line 7
```

which additionally uses `tee` to duplicate the data.

Comment: Ok I think function is the solution for the single command thank you .

Answer (score 2):

```
head -n3 input | tail -n1; head -n7 input | tail -n1
```

use `head` to get the first three lines then `tail` only the last 1.  Then use `head` to get the first seven lines and `tail` only the last 1.

Note that is actually two commands separated by `;`, it may be possible in a single command but I'm not sure how.

Using `sed` would probably be better:

```
sed -n '3p;7p' input
```

---

If it needs to be a single command, make your own command (function):

```
get_lines () {
    local input=$1
    shift
    for line; do
        head -n "$line" "$input" | tail -n 1
    done
}
```

You would call this like:

```
$ get_lines input 3 7
This is line 3
This is line 7
```

Where `input` is the name of your file.  This will also accept as many or as few line numbers as you want:

```
$ get_lines input 1 3 5 7 9
This is line 1
This is line 3
This is line 5
This is line 7
This is line 9
```

Comment: Yes sed is better I forgot to say that I did the attempt using head and tail and it works but the question is how to do it using only one command

Comment: Thank you Jesse

Comment: @PerplexeÉmotionnellement: I've added a hack, do you think that would be accepted?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more ?

Comment: @PerplexeÉmotionnellement He's basically written a function that extracts a specific line from a file.  The _function_ uses only the `head` and `tail` external commands. The rest is pure shell (built-in functionality). You could also obviously do it without using _any_ external command, not even `head` or `tail`, by simply reading the lines in the shell while counting them.